nginx location matching issue
I have two locations defined as:
 location /api/reviewerhub/ {
    proxy_pass http://reviewerhub:80/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600; 
}

and
  location /api/revieweraddin/ {
    proxy_pass http://revieweraddin:80/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600; 
}

After some deployments, requests to reviewerhub are mapping to revieweraddin and vice-versa.
My best guess is that it is doing some sort of lazy pattern matching, but this is very speculative.
Is this an issue with the location matching? If it is not, then what else could it be? If it is, can I change this so that the location matching works reliably without changing the URLs?
nginx version is 1.17.1.
Issue can be temporarily resolved by restarting nginx. After a few deployments it recurs. Unclear if the recurrence is arbitrary or the result of some specific scenario. The issue occurs (or not) on a per-deployment basis, not a per-request basis.
